# C# GMap.Net Calculate Zoom value with latitude and longitude min and max

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary, zooming

I'm coding a windows form application using a GMap control.
I have many roads and i would like to adapt the gmap zoom value in order to fit all my roads on the map.
I have the latitude and longitude min and max of all my roads.
I'm working with C#.

Comment: Someone ? Please help !

Answer (score 2):

use gmap function ZoomAndCenterMarkers or ZoomAndCenterRoute or ZoomAndCenterRoutes

Example:

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");

GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688, 32.580528),
  GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);

GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-43.966688, 11.580528),
  GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);


gMap.ZoomAndCenterMarkers("markers");
```